# How to chant Sahastranama Stotram?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, kali, sahasranama

Can anyone pronounce **Sahastranama Stotram**?

Is it ok if I mispronounce some names, can I take the help of YouTube videos to chant?

Comment: Try Sadhana App by Om Swami.Afaik it contains Surya,Durga,Lakshmi,Gayatri and Vishnu Sahasranamam, if unsure of pronunciations you can chk that out :)

Comment: Sahasranama - सहस्र नाम , स्तोत्रम् . You can learn to pronounce by listening to audio, and also by referring to individual 'naama' so that you don't mis-pronounce. It helps to know the sandhi rules of Sanskrit.